# Webpack asset generator with publicPath not working?

Tags: webpack, generator

when upgrading webpack to version 5.64.0, `module.rule.generator.publicPath` has stopped working properly.

```
module.exports={
  // ....,
  generator: {
    filename: devMode
      ? "../fonts/[name][ext][query]"
      : "fonts/[name][hash][ext][query]",
    publicPath: "fonts",
  },
}
```

and I have this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/frontlib.sass
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugi/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Invalid URL at tryRunOrWebpackError
```

Now I still have the same error even if I downgrade Webpack to the previous version.

**How to set generator `publicPath` into the new Webpack version?**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but i got it to work.
The generator does not support publicPath. You have to use the output of the compiler.

```
...

entry: {
    main: './src/inputFile.js'
},
output: {
    filename: 'outputName.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../outputFolder')
}

...

{
    test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
    type: "asset/resource",
    generator: {
        filename: './fonts/[hash][ext]'
    }
}
```

I have an example in this repo:
https://github.com/Vanillabacke/webpack-5-settings